# Enabling DNS server scavenging using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, dns, windows-server

I am trying to enable scavenging on a Windows Server 2022 DNS server using PowerShell. Aging at the zone level has been configured using [Set-DnsServerZoneAging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/set-dnsserverzoneaging), but I am unable to enable scavenging at the server level using [Set-DnsServerScavenging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/set-dnsserverscavenging):

```
$timeSpan = New-TimeSpan -Days 7
Set-DnsServerScavenging `
  -ScavengingState $true `
  -RefreshInterval $timeSpan `
  -NoRefreshInterval $timeSpan
```

Is it possible to enable scavenging at the server level using PowerShell as per the image below?

[image]

Comment: Do you get an error when running the cmdlet?  I notice in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/set-dnsserverscavenging?view=windowsserver2019-ps) that there is a computername parameter.  Maybe try using it?

Comment: I do not get any errors. I have tried with the computer parameter specified without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbox you indicated is enabled via the Set-DnsServerScavenging command.

Try running it as follows:

```
Set-DnsServerScavenging `
    -ScavengingState $true `
    -RefreshInterval $timeSpan `
    -NoRefreshInterval $timeSpan `
    -ScavengingInterval $timeSpan
```

That last param is the key. If ScavengingInterval is not set, then the checkbox remains in its default state (unchecked).